# Cannot build project asp.net 5 project referencing portable class library

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, roslyn, class-library

I have vNext WebApplication project, that references my WebFramework class library (portable). If both projects are in one solution, I can build WebApplication, however if I try to compile another project with class libary provided as deployed nuget package, there is error: "Type or namespace name 'WebFramework' does not exist".

Package is referenced in project.json, and is restored correctly (no errors reported). How I can fix this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a diagnostic build log of the error and post it somewhere? This would either be from a command line build msbuild /v:diag or changing the options under Tools > Options in Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have Copy Local property correctly set to True?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Project isn't even built by msbuild. It's asp.net 5 vNext project.